# AngularJs: Visualize table only on click of a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie in angularjs. I am trying to display a table on click.

I have a button like below

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" ng-click="getDataCatalogue()"><span class="network-name">Data Catalogue</span></a></br></br>
```

and, I have a table as below

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Script which parses json data

```
 $scope.getDataCatalogue = function(){

           $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')
               .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                     //do something with your response
                     $scope.people = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: "Peter",
      lastName: "Jhons"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: "David",
      lastName: "Bowie"
    }
];
               })
               .error(function(error){
                     console.log("not world");
               });
      }
```

How to make the table visible in a seperate div and redirected to a separate page containing the table on clicking the button "Data Catalogue".

Comment: do you mean something like `ng-show` or `ng-if`?

Comment: yes, In my case the button is a separate anchor tag and the dive is a separate html entity. I am unable toi link both by using on click event.